# Who was רבינו יואל מבונ"א?

Tags: rishonim

I came across a רבינו יואל מבונ"א quoted by Rosh in his commentary to Kiddushin (4:16). See [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%A9%22%D7%A1/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%93#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.98.D7.95). Who is he?

I suspect that he is Rabbeinu Yoel HaLevi, father of [Ra'avyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_ben_Joel_HaLevi) and that בונ"א is what we know today as the city of Bonn in Germany.

Can anyone provide a confirmation or a refutation of my suspicions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct and confirmed by Aptowitzer ([Intro. to 'Ravia', pg. 39](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21884&st=&pgnum=48)), Urbach (Ba'alei HaTosafos, Jer. 1969, pg. 179) and Ginzberg ([JE, Eliezer b. Joel](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/5614-eliezer-ben-joel-ha-levi)). His full name was Yoel b. Yitzchok HaLevi. He was born in the first quarter of the 12th century and died at the turn of the next. He was also a son in-law of R. Eliezer b. Nathan (Ravan, ראב״ן). Note, Aptowitzer believes that he was originally from Mainz, though ultimately settled and operated his school in Bonn.

Comment: יישר כוח.......

Comment: @kouty ברוכים תהיו